# EntityNotFoundException in JPA when run in a transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I have a simple scenario with **Spring**, **JPA**, **Hibernate**. In the application, there is an entity which is called `Contact` without any relations by one-to-one or one-to-many annotations.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_contact")
public class Contact 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When I load an instance of `Contact` which doesn't exist in the database by **JpaTemplate** class in **Spring** the result is null, but when I load the same record in a transaction (**Transactional** annotation), an **EntityNotFoundException** is thrown. I want to check null situation of the entity by myself, but in that behavior, I'm forced to catch the exception and then, continue my logic. 
I'm confused by this behavior and want to know is there any solution that help me?

Comment: `JpaTemplate` shouldn't be used, but it catches the exception and returns `null`, when using a plain `EntityManager` it will throw an exception as defined by the contract of `EntityManager.find`.

Comment: I test it without JpaTemplate, but the result is the same. Actually I don't want to catch the exception manually and I'm looking for the main reason in the difference between in or not a transaction.

Comment: I would expect the behavior to be the same and that is throwing an exception as that is what the `EntityManager.find` does. The `JpaTemplate` might translate that to a Spring `DataAccessException`. Regardless the only save way is to catch the exception and handle it.